Подключение html страницы к moodle
У меня есть html страница с формой для авторизации. Также у меня установлен moodle. Мне нужно осуществлять авторизацию на html странице, а не в самом moodle. Как это подключить эту страницу с авторизацией к платформе moodle? версия moodle 4.4.1
